# How to use the Angular In-Memory Web API .data attribute?

Tags: angular

My goal is to use in-memory-web-api interchangeably with a real backend.

As stated in the Angular 2 (or 4) Tour of Heroes tutorial https://angular.io/tutorial/toh-pt6#extracting-the-data-in-the-then-callback :

> Note the shape of the data that the server returns. This particular
>   in-memory web API example returns an object with a data property. Your
>   API might return something else. Adjust the code to match your web
>   API.

The mocked web api service returns an object wrapped in a data attribute. The problem is that my backend doesn't return the data in that format, it doesn't have a "data" attribute.

```
.then(response => response.json().data as Hero[])
```

should be

```
.then(response => response.json() as Hero[])
```

and hopefully it should work. If I change it to the second version, the in-memory api doesn't work anymore...

Is there a way that I can change in-memory-web-api to actually remove that data attribute?

Comment: @Graham Please also remove the tags from the titles in your next edits. [See this meta-answer for more information](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/130208/305455). (I will delete this comment when you a acknowledged it, so please do it as well when you add a comment)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here's my solution for this:

```js
import { InMemoryDbService, RequestInfo } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import {  ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    myData = 'any data';
    createDb() {
        let myData = this.myData;
        return {myData};
    }

    protected responseInterceptor(res: ResponseOptions, ri: RequestInfo): ResponseOptions {
        res.body = this.myData;
        return res;
    }
    
}
```

By default, in-memory-db would return {data: 'any data'} in it's body. In responseInterceptor you can change it to any type of data you want.
Of course, this is very simplified version.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know about that interceptor. myData in my case has multiple "endpoints", so I did this in the responseInterceptor: res.body = this.data[ri.collectionName];

Answer (score 2):

A slight tweak on @Ann's answer. I return multiple types of data from my IMDB so I needed to make it a little more generic:

```
import { InMemoryDbService, RequestInfo } from 'angular-in-memory-web-api';
import {  ResponseOptions } from '@angular/http';

class AnyData{
    data: any;
}

export class InMemoryDataService implements InMemoryDbService {
    createDb() {
        let myDataA = [{...}];
        let myDataB = [{...}];
        let myDataC = [{...}];
        return { "A":myDataA,
           "B":myDataB,
           "C":myDataC };
    }

    protected responseInterceptor(res: ResponseOptions, ri: RequestInfo): ResponseOptions {
        let wrapped:AnyData = <AnyData> res.body;
        res.body = wrapped.data;
        return res;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

They have now made an option to choose whether to encapsulate the response with the data part or not.

> **HTTP response data no longer wrapped in object w/ data property**
>
> As of v0.5.0 (5 October 2017), the dataEncapsulation configuration
>   default changed from false to true. The HTTP response body holds the
>   data values directly rather than an object that encapsulates those
>   values, {data: ...}.
>
> https://github.com/angular/in-memory-web-api

In your app.module.ts, in the imports array you can use the dataEncapsulation flag to choose how you want to have it return:

```
HttpClientInMemoryWebApiModule.forRoot(
    InMemoryDataService, { delay: 0, dataEncapsulation: false }
)
```